# How to get a substring of a current link in PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, substring

I am having this PHP link :

```
http://localhost/OnlineShop/show_cat.php?catid=1
```

I want to be able to get the substring value of the link after the "=" and to visualize it on the same page. In this case is 1.

Comment: You can use PHPs `GET` for that

Comment: Come on, isn't this explained in EVERY PHP tutorial in existence?

Comment: But is there a way to do it with substrings ?

Comment: Maybe he means to say that he has that link as a ***string***

Answer (score 8):

Use can simple use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) For getting parameter value from url.

You can do somthing like this:

```
$url ="http://localhost/OnlineShop/show_cat.php?catid=1";
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['catid'];
```

## [DEMO](http://codepad.org/EGu0uZxI)

Want less code??? try simpler method as @Hanky웃Panky Suggest:

```
$url ="http://localhost/OnlineShop/show_cat.php?catid=1";
parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
echo $query['catid'];
```

## [DEMO](http://codepad.org/8TXek0KB)

Comment: `parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);`  That way you don't need that 1 extra line and an extra variable

Comment: Thanks @Hanky웃Panky. You are correct i agree with you.

Comment: You can add it to your answer then:)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I have added in my answer. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If this is on your server, you can use `$_GET` superglobal (like the other answers have suggested)

```
if( array_key_exists('catid', $_GET) ) {
  echo $_GET['catid'];
}
```

But, if you want to evaluate the URL, without it being in the address bar; use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) and a mixture of string manipulators.

```
$arrUrl = parse_url('http://localhost/OnlineShop/show_cat.php?catid=1');

echo $intCatId = filter_var($arrUrl['query'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

https://eval.in/186415

#### Documentation

- [filter_var](https://www.php.net/filter_var)
- [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url)
- [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

  - [_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

You want like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['catid'])){

      echo $_GET['catid']; 

}
```

Comment: Nope I read like (If the case is 1 instead In this case is 1.) After read, I edited

Answer (score 0):

```
explode("=", $sting)[1]
```

There are a lot of ways.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be a way:

```
$string = "http://localhost/OnlineShop/show_cat.php?catid=1";
$id = substr($string, strpos($string, '=') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Print Variable Like This

> if(isset($_GET['catid'])){ echo $_GET['catid']; }

OR

You can also use

> $_REQUEST['catid']

For Access It.